Reaction of prenol with thionyl chloride
What would be the major product of the reaction between prenol and thionyl chloride?

I thought when an allylic alcohol is present in the reaction with $\ce{SOCl2},$ it does SN2' reaction instead of regularly substituting the $\ce{OH}$ group due to the formation of stable six-membered cyclic transition state (6-MCTS).
But for prenol the answer was given as normal substitution of alcohol by substituting it with $\ce{Cl}.$ Can anyone explain the reason?

Honestly, does every reaction need to pass the benchmark for 6 MCTS to be the reletively more appropriate mechanism? For instance, if the reaction can go along well by the simple substitution, does it need to check for the possibilities of a 6 membered ring? I want to know if there is any rule as such, I am curious. Or maybe, thats just how some reactions proceed?
